# Read and split a column values from a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataset, where the second column looks like this.

```
FileName
892e7c8382943342a29a6ae5a55f2272532d8e04.exe.asm
2d42c1b2c33a440d165683eeeec341ebf61218a1.exe.asm
1fbab6b4566a2465a8668bbfed21c0bfaa2c2eed.exe.asm
```

Now, I want to extract the name before ".exe.asm" from the column and append it to a new list for all the rows of my dataset. I tried the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("dataset1.csv")
exekey = []

for row in df.iterrows():
    exekey.append(row[1].split('.'))
exekey
```

This execution gave me the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'split'
```

I am not able to do it. Please help

On changing, the output was of the form [Output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LoKu3.png)

Comment: Could you please add `as is` and `expected` to your question?

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar still not getting the intended output. 


    FileName    [e62c764a18642df4fc82886aa0b0e14cb54d6f1b, exe...
    1                                                         NaN
    2                                                         NaN
    3                                                         NaN
    4                                                         NaN
    5                                                         NaN
    6                                                         NaN

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar I have done the asked changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the `filename` using `.` and access 1st element using indexing.

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame({'FileName':['892e7c8382943342a29a6ae5a55f2272532d8e04.exe.asm',
'2d42c1b2c33a440d165683eeeec341ebf61218a1.exe.asm',
'1fbab6b4566a2465a8668bbfed21c0bfaa2c2eed.exe.asm']})


exekey = [i.split(".")[0] for i in df['FileName']]
print(exekey)
```

**Alternate way**:

```
exekey2 = df['FileName'].apply(lambda x: x.split(".")[0]).tolist()
```

Output:

```
['892e7c8382943342a29a6ae5a55f2272532d8e04', '2d42c1b2c33a440d165683eeeec341ebf61218a1', '1fbab6b4566a2465a8668bbfed21c0bfaa2c2eed']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` like this to split on `.` and take index `0`,

```
df['FileName'].map(lambda f : f.split('.')[0])

# Output

0    892e7c8382943342a29a6ae5a55f2272532d8e04
1    2d42c1b2c33a440d165683eeeec341ebf61218a1
2    1fbab6b4566a2465a8668bbfed21c0bfaa2c2eed
Name: FileName, dtype: object
```

If you want to get a list of names you can do,

```
df['FileName'].map(lambda f : f.split('.')[0]).values.tolist()

# Output : ['892e7c8382943342a29a6ae5a55f2272532d8e04',
            '2d42c1b2c33a440d165683eeeec341ebf61218a1',
            '1fbab6b4566a2465a8668bbfed21c0bfaa2c2eed']
```